# cyclic import from parent folder, caused "cannot perform relative import" error

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a module from parent folder, the folder structure is like this

```
├───src
│   └───graph.py
│       
├───model.py 
└───main.py
```

in main.py

```
from scr.graph import graph
from model import model
```

in model.py

```
from src.graph import notation 

# do something
```

in graph.py I'm trying to import model

```
from ..model import model
```

Then I got error

```
SystemError: Parent module 'src.graph' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I know this is a cyclic import, and I should put some of modules together.

I've searched some of answers to avoid the cyclic import like

1.Defer import until later

2.import the module only without loading the whole file

but I not sure how to perfrom this, and my error seems not relevant to cyclic import,  is there anyone could show me how to fix this ?

Comment: is there any particular reason why you wouldn't put model in src

Comment: @d_kennetz No.. I was adding extra feature to the program, then I found that I need to use the model